# Race condition with Python mmap and multiprocessing.semaphore

Tags: python, concurrency, mmap

I am writing a script that processes some mmaps concurrently with multiprocessing.Process and updates a result list stored in an mmap and locked with a mutex.

My function to write to the result list looks like this

```
def update_result(result_mmap, new_value, new_value_index, sema):
    sema.acquire()
    result_mmap.seek(0)
    old_result = result_mmap.readline().split("\t")
    old_result[new_value_index] = new_value
    new_result = "\t".join(map(str, old_result))
    result_mmap.resize(len(new_result))
    result_mmap.seek(0)
    result_mmap.write(new_result)
    sema.release()
```

This works SOMETIMES, but other times, depending on the order of execution of the processes, it seems that the result_mmap isn't resizing properly. I am not sure where to look from here- I know that a race condition exists but I don't know why.

Edit: This is the function that calls `update_result`:

```
def apply_function(mmapped_files, function, result_mmap, result_index, sema):
    for mf in mmapped_files:
        accumulator = int(mf.readline())
        while True:
            line = mf.readline()
            if line is None or line == '':
                break
            num = int(line)
            accumulator = function(num, accumulator)
        update_result(result_mmap, result_index, inc, sema)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the `update_result` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but are you sure that the semaphore really works between the processes (is it a system mutex?). Because if it's not, processes do not share the same memory space. What you might want to consider using would be the threading library, in order for the threads to use the same semaphore.

Comment: I think you're right- I removed the semaphore lines and the program behaves much like it did with them.  I want to avoid using threads because I need this to run in parallel, and as I understand it the GIL won't allow that.

Comment: Threads are in parallel. They will simply use the same memory space and the same processor unit. A process has multiple threads in parallel.

Comment: Maybe I should have said concurrently instead of parallel. Whichever it is that the GIL prevents, I need. I am going to redesign this with the result list in a database so I don't have to take care of the locking myself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the point of `multiprocessing` having a `semaphore` member if it's not a cross-process semaphore? That seems to defeat the point of having a semaphore class in a module designed for running multiple processes concurrently. Or is it simply that you have to keep the semaphore in a shared memory space/explicitly pass it to all created processes somehow?

Comment: It's because some OS such as UNIX have system semaphores (in a limited number). I do not know if there are in Windows or if they are accessible. With the OS managed semaphores, you can operate cross process.

Comment: Also, just noticed that `multiprocessing` also has a `Lock` class, which seems to effectively be a binary semaphore. Does that do anything between processes? -- http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects, seems to imply that `multiprocessing`'s `Lock`s do indeed work on a system level rather than per-process.

Comment: @Alexandre: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx, Windows does indeed support system semaphores. "Named system semaphores are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes."

Comment: And I just noticed that right at the top of the documentation, it gives an example of using a `multiprocess.Lock` object. http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes